# Not expected at this time error in batch

Tags: shell, batch-file

I created a batch script and it was complete enough that I could run it so I loaded it up and I get an error `=1 was not expected at this time` but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, originally I had `if armor=1 ( do...)` but I got the same error both times, can someone tell me what I did wrong and why this happens?

```
:prebattle
cls
if armor == 1 (
set php=100
)
set /a mlvl=%random% %% 5 + 1 

if weapon=1 (
set pdmg=%random% %% 20 + 1
)
if !lvl! geq 1 if !lvl! leq 5 (
set enemyno=%random% %% 3 + 1
set mdmg=%random% %% 20 + 1
)
if !lvl! geq 6 if !lvl! leq 10 (
set enemyno=%random% %% 5 + 1
set mdmg=%random% %% 50 + 1
)
if !lvl! geq 11 if !lvl! leq 15 (
set enemyno=%random% %% 9 + 1
set mdmg=%random% %% 100 + 1
)
if !lvl! geq 21 if !lvl! leq 30 (
set enemyno=%random% %% 15 + 1
set mdmg=%random% %% 150 + 1
)
if !lvl! geq 31 if !lvl! leq 45 (
set enemyno=%random% %% 20 + 1
set mdmg=%random% %% 200 + 1
)
if !lvl! geq 46 if !lvl! leq 60 (
enemyno=%random% %% 30 + 1
set mdmg=%random% %% 500 + 1
)
if enemyno == 1 (
goto enemy1
)
if enemyno=2 (
goto enemy2
)
if enemyno=3 (
goto enemy3
)
if enemyno=4 (
goto enemy4
)
if enemyno=5 (
goto enemy5
)
if enemyno=6 (
goto enemy6
)
if enemyno=7 (
goto enemy7
)
if enemyno=8 (
goto enemy8
)
if enemyno=9 (
goto enemy9
)
if enemyno=10 (
goto enemy10
)
if enemyno=11 (
goto enemy11
)
if enemyno=12 (
goto enemy12
)
if enemyno=13 (
goto enemy13
)
if enemyno=14 (
goto enemy14
)
if enemyno=15 (
goto enemy15
)
if enemyno=16 (
goto enemy16
)
if enemyno=17 (
goto enemy17
)
if enemyno=18 (
goto enemy18
)
if enemyno=19 (
goto enemy19
)
if enemyno=20 (
goto enemy20
)
if enemyno=21 (
goto enemy21
)
if enemyno=22 (
goto enemy22
)
if enemyno=23 (
goto enemy23
)
if enemyno=24 (
goto enemy24
)
if enemyno=25 (
goto enemy25
)
if enemyno=26 (
goto enemy26
)
if enemyno=27 (
goto enemy27
)
if enemyno=28 (
goto enemy28
)
if enemyno=29 (
goto enemy29
)
if enemyno=30 (
goto enemy30
)
goto prebattle
```

Comment: `if armor == 1`  This is a string comparison.  You are not comparing the value of the variable armor.  `if weapon=1`  The help for the `IF` command says to use two `=` for string comparison.  And again you are comparing weapon to 1 and not the value of the variable.

Comment: @Squashman I already set the variable armor to 1 further up, so that isn't it

Comment: Ugh!  You are not using the variable.  To reference a variable you need to use percent symbols.  `%armor%`

Comment: There is no need to use delayed expansion of your `lvl` variable.

Comment: @Squashman OMFG IM AN IDIOT

Comment: @Squashman  thanks I didn't realise that

Comment: I told you in your previous question that you did not need to use delayed expansion for your variables.

Comment: Instead of doing this this thirty times: `if enemyno == 1 (goto enemy1)`. You can just do this. `GOTO enemy%enemyno%`

Comment: BTW, a question that includes code should have *the smallest amount of code that will produce the same problem*. You should be able to reproduce this with only one `if` statement, rather than needing 30. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

These are the two biggest errors:

Using enemyno instead of %enemyno%. You only use the not percent version when setting variables.

Your if equation needs two == or EQU for it to work. Your fixed command should look like:

```
if %enemyno%==7 goto enemy7
```

I don't use the () because it is not always needed.

I also see that you are using

```
set enemyno=%random% %% 30 + 1
```

which needs /a to work, otherwise it will take it as a string. (/a makes it save as numbers.)
It will look like:

```
set /a enemyno=%random% %%30 +1
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Im relatively new to batch scripting so thanks for the explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing in an if statement so you need two equal signs or use EQU.

if weapon == 1 (goto label)

if weapon EQU 1 (goto label)

Comment: I already stated that in my comments above and your code is still incorrect because the variable is not being expanded to the value.  You need to use percent symbols to expand the variable to its value.

Comment: @Yoshirou, I am just stating the facts.  If you want to use incorrect code, go right ahead.